# how to find Group By in grails using createCriteria

Tags: grails

I have a domain

```
class File{
  String fileName
  String account
  int fileSize
}
```

i have to find filesize group by account like this

```
account1 = filesize1+filesize2.....
account2= fs1+fs2+.....
```

so how can i create a GORM query using criteria
thank

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below query

```
 def fileList = File.createCriteria().list(){
  projections{
    groupProperty "account"
    sum "fileSize"
  }
}
```

or

```
File.executeQuery("Select sum(f.fileSize) from File f group by f.account")
```

Comment: exception is comming---- argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [account]

Comment: @user3068680 give full stack trace

Comment: Line | Method
->>   72 | doCall            in com.project.analytics.FileAnalyticsController$_sizeData_closure3_closure5$$EOQRGxqC
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    990 | invokeClosureNode in grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder
|    376 | projections . . . in     ''
|     71 | doCall            in com.project.analytics.FileAnalyticsController$_sizeData__closure3$$EOQRGxqC

Comment: thanks for ur suppor .sorry for this i am using mongo db which doesnot support group by.